# Ruby 1.8.7 vs 1.9* String[Fixnum] differences

Tags: ruby, string

Ruby 1.8.7:

```
"abc"[0]
=> 65
```

Ruby 1.9*

```
"abc"[0]
=> "a"
```

Is there a way I can safely write the code above to produce the second result in both 1.8.7 and 1.9*? My solution so far is: `"abc".split('').first` but that doesn't seem very clever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"abc"[0].chr
```

produces the 2nd result in both versions.

1.8: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Integer.html#method-i-chr
1.9: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chr

Answer (score 5):

If you want the first character of a string, as a string, then add a length in the brackets:

"abc"[0,1]

Comment: Another way of doing that is `"abc"[0..0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in 1.8, most of these answers will only work for characters in the ASCII range:

```
irb(main):001:0>  "ā"[0].chr
=> "\304"
irb(main):002:0>  "ā"[0,1]
=> "\304"
irb(main):003:0>  "ā"[0..0]
=> "\304"
```

Though of course it depends on your encoding.

Answer (score -1):

What about
    "abc"[0].ord
?

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-ord

Comment: Oh yeah, I taught he wanted to emulate the 1.8.* result. I'll remember not to try to answer on SO when I'm sleepy.